# Can TrueOS be installed on Apple Mac hardware?

Tags: macintosh, trueos

I would like to try using [TrueOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueOS) as an alternative to [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) on Apple Mac hardware having 64-bit Intel chips such as MacBook Pro.

The [system requirements page](https://www.trueos.org/handbook/introducing.html#hardware-requirements-and-supported-hardware) in the TrueOS User Guide do not say anything specific about Apple Mac hardware. The mentioned requirements of 1-4 gigs of memory and a 64-bit processor are met by modern Macs.

➜ Can TrueOS be installed on modern Mac hardware?

I do *not* care about [dual-booting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-booting). I do not care about supporting [Apple Boot Camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_(software)). I am asking about a simple wipe-the-drive and install only TrueOS operation.

Comment: An Intel-based Mac is just a standard PC with a specific set of components (and a UEFI without BIOS compatibility mode). Without knowing the exact model, though, we won't know for sure that those components are supported. Try it. Chances are good that the answer is "yes"

Comment: I agree with Fox's comment. Try to boot it from a Live USB or DVD - if that works, then it should work with a full install.